# Why my code showing "Blended transforms not yet supported.", and plt.show() is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

This is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Slider

# The function to be called anytime a slider's value changes
def update():
    line.set_ydata(bin_slider.val)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def reset(reset):
    bin_slider.reset()
    button.on_clicked(reset)

# data
csv_file = '/Users/nguyenminh/Downloads/data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

Radial_Distance_SD = data['RadialDistanceSD'] 

plt.hist(Radial_Distance_SD)
plt.xlabel('Radial Distance')
plt.ylabel('Density')
plt.title("Histogram of RadialDistanceSD")

# Create the figure and the line that we will manipulate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(Radial_Distance_SD)

# adjust the main plot to make room for the sliders
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

# Make a horizontal slider to control the bin.
axbin = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
bin_slider = Slider(ax=axbin,label='Bins',valmin=0.1,valmax=30)

# register the update function with each slider
bin_slider.on_changed(update)

# Create a matplotlib.widgets.Button to reset the sliders to initial values.

resetax = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', hovercolor='0.975')

plt.show()
```

I tried `plt.show(block=True)` and it is still not working.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?  Could you provide some test data (as text or as code)? Are you calling `plt.hist()` before you created a new figure? Do you want to have that together with a curve drawn by `ax.plot(Radial_Distance_SD)`?  Please first try to get your code working without the sliders.  If you get an error, can you tell which line generated that error? And [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77951413/edit) the full error trace to your post?

Comment: What I mean is the code is running, but it doesn't show the graph. I tried to rerun my code without the sliders, and it still does not give me any graph, it returns nothing, but it doesn't have the line that says "Blended transform not yet supported" in this case.

Comment: Could you also answer and act on the other questions?  Did you move `plt.hist(Radial_Distance_SD)` etc. after the creation of the figure?

Comment: You should add a basic example of your data so we can test the code